# Ruby on Rails bundle command not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

All of a sudden I'm no longer able to run the bundle command in my project. I'm using Ubuntu for development and was following a tutorial on how to deploy to Azure.

When I cd to my project directory and runn bundle I get the following message:-

```
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.1.0/kgio-2.9.2 (Errno::EACCES)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250:in `fu_mkdir'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:222:in `reverse_each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:222:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:208:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:208:in `mkdir_p'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:210:in `write_gem_make_out'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:132:in `build_error'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:171:in `rescue in build_extension'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:156:in `build_extension'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in find_inactive_by_path'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/net/http/persistent.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendored_persistent.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/fetcher.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli.rb:239:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:121:in `invoke_command'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:20:in `<main>'
```

I'm in way over my head. Has anyone any idea what I've done to break it or how I can fix it

Comment: Looks like you have a permissions problem at /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.1.0/kgio-2.9.2 Do you have all the rights to write to that directory?

Comment: Its a virual machine running on virtualbox so I should have all the rights? I'll try and create a file there

Comment: Just looked and there's no file or directory called kgio-2.9.2 in that directory?

Comment: All that's there is bcrypt-3.1.9 and pg-0.17.1

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the stack trace,

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250:in `mkdir': 
  Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - 
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.1.0/kgio-2.9.2 (Errno::EACCES)
    ...
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:208:in `mkdir_p'
    ...
```

bundler is trying to create the directory: `/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.1.0/kgio-2.9.2`.  It is using the equivalent of `mkdir -p`, which will "create intermediate directories as required." (see `man mkdir`).  So, you need permission to create that directory.

If you're not familiar with unix permissions, you'll have to do some reading, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions

Some tools that will be useful include cd, ls -l, chown, and chmod.  Don't use them until you've read their manuals, especially chown and chmod.

Comment: I'll start reading the docs now. Is there any reason why bundler can't write to that particular directory? I've just tried to create one there in terminal but it said 'mkdir: cannot create directory ‘alzer’: Permission denied'. Then I used sudo and was able to create one

Comment: I'm a bit slow tonight. Just had to run sudo bundle install and it installed the necessary gems. I was about to start chown(ing) directories. Thank god I copped on. Who knows what I would have done. Thanks for your help

Comment: Just be aware that when you use `sudo` the files you create are owned by `root`.  `sudo` stands for "super-user do".  `root` is the super-user.  It's commonly held to be a mistake to install gems as root, but in the case of a VM maybe it's reasonable?  I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

just remove `.bundle` directory in your application path

Comment: Thanks. I moved to an Ubuntu dual boot on my laptop so all is sorted